# What does $X = x$ mean in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, definition

What does $Y = y$ and $X = x$ mean?
Why are they equal?
$$
P(Y=y \mid X=x)=\frac{P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(X=x)}
$$

Comment: Why do you think they are "equal"?

Comment: It's not true in general. It's true only if $\mathbb P\{X=x\}>0$.

Comment: X and Y are random variables while x and y are particular values they might take. The $P(Y=y\mid X=x)$ is read as "The probability that the random variable Y has the value y given that the random variable X has the value x".

Comment: Thanks alot @Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and a random variable $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, the proposed notation is a shortcut for $\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(\{x\}))$, where $X^{-1}(\cdot)$ represents the notation for inverse images.

**EDIT**

Suppose that the random variable $X$ represents the height and the random variable $Y$ represents the weight associated to some population. So you can interpret the statement
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X = x | Y = y) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X = x,Y = y)}{\mathbb{P}(Y = y)}
\end{align*}
as the probability that a member of the population has height $X = x$ given that its weight is $Y = y$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I am pretty sure this notation is too heavy for the OP. Paul's comment is ideal.

Comment: @roro I have edited my answer.